# Need help adding icon in .inc file

Tags: php, include

All Im trying to do is add small icon next to the exif data in my install script so it will display next to the name text. How do you add and link images in db_insert

This is my install code and all works great but can add icons next to it.

```
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'1',"name"=>"File name","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"fnl"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'2',"name"=>"File size","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"siz"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'3',"name"=>"Date/Time","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"cdt"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'4',"name"=>"Dimensions","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"dim"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'5',"name"=>"Camera model","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"exif_model"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'6',"name"=>"Sensitivity","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"exif_iso"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'7',"name"=>"Shutter speed","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"exif_exp_time"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'8',"name"=>"Aperture","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"exif_f"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'9',"name"=>"Focal Length","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"exif_fl"));
db_insert("photo_param",Array("id"=>'10',"name"=>"Date/Time(Exif)","type"=>"system","default_lov"=>"exif_datetime"));
```

Comment: How about some PHP code.  And what text and what icon?

Comment: I have added a some more so not sure if I have to add it inside my SQL db or install file. Also a small icons like on flickr that displays the info about the camera